# Java annotations in odd places

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Browsing through the source of a spring framework project i came across a method that looked like this:

```
@RequestMapping("primitive")
public @ResponseBody String primitive(@RequestParam Integer value) {
    return "Converted primitive " + value;
}
```

Being only a casual java user, ive not come across this before. As far as i was aware, the @ symbol preceded java annotations, yet there appear to be annotations in the method signature itself. What are the `@ResponseBody` and `@RequestParam` sections doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `@ResponseBody` is actually just a Plain-Jane [Method annotation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html#method).  You're allowed to put them after the scope keyword.

The `@RequestParam` annotation isn't part of the method signature. It's a [Parameter Annotation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html#parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Those annotations are specific to Spring, so you'll need to dive into Spring to learn all the annotations and what they mean.

Whenever I need to learn something new in Spring, I always jump back to the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

It's good to read through that whole thing at least once in your life, if you plan on using Spring for enterprise development.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations can be added in many places within Java code.  A good way to find out exactly where is to look at the [`@Target`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) meta-annotation.  This annotation is applied to other annotations to describe to the compiler the locations that are valid for it to live.  Anyways, the `@Target` annotation takes an array of [`ElementType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html), and this enumeration has all the valid locations to apply annotations to.

As of Java 6, the `ElementType` enum contains these values:

`ANNOTATION_TYPE`, `CONSTRUCTOR`, `FIELD`, `LOCAL_VARIABLE`, `METHOD`, `PACKAGE`, `PARAMETER` and `TYPE`

In your example, `@RequestMapping` and `@ResponseBody` are both `METHOD` level annotations, even though they are not applied in the exact same location (one before the method scope modifier and one after), and `@RequestParam` is a `PARAMETER` level annotation.